# External display thinks it is on previous low-resolution one

Tags: display, resolution

If I use a low-resolution external monitor or video projector on my MBP 16"(2019) and later connect to a high resolution monitor, the Mac cannot recognize the new monitor, so the monitor only offers low resolutions (even with Option-click-Scaled). Is there a quick way to tell the Mac to forget about the previous external display, besides rebooting the Mac?

Comment: How are you connecting?

Comment: In my first experience, I first hooked my MBP to a poor-resolution monitor with HDMI and an HDMI to USB-c adapter, and later I hooked the MBP to a high resolution monitor with the same adapter. In my second experience, I first hooked my MBP to a VGA cable of a video projector using the VGA entry of a 13-slot multi-to-USB-C adapter (by ZMUIPNG), and later hooked my MBP to a monitor with my HDMI to USB-C adapter.